# Pandas: Applying Lambda to Multiple Data Frames

Tags: python, memory, pandas, lambda, dataframe

I'm trying to figure out how to apply a lambda function to multiple dataframes simultaneously, without first merging the data frames together. I am working with large data sets (>60MM records) and I need to be extra careful with memory management.

My hope is that there is a way to apply lambda to just the underlying dataframes so that I can avoid the cost of stitching them together first, and then dropping that intermediary dataframe from memory before I move on to the next step in the process.

I have experience dodging out of memory issues by using HDF5 based dataframes, but I'd rather try exploring something different first.

I have provided a toy problem to help demonstrate what I am talking about.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Here's an arbitrary function to use with lambda
def someFunction(input1, input2, input3, input4):
    theSum = input1 + input2
    theAverage = (input1 + input2 + input3 + input4) / 4
    theProduct = input2 * input3 * input4
    return pd.Series({'Sum' : theSum, 'Average' : theAverage, 'Product' : theProduct})

# Cook up some dummy dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,1),columns=list('C'))
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,1),columns=list('D'))

# Currently, I merge the dataframes together and then apply the lambda function
dfConsolodated = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)

# This works just fine, but merging the dataframes seems like an extra step
dfResults = dfConsolodated.apply(lambda x: someFunction(x['A'], x['B'], x['C'], x['D']), axis = 1)

# I want to avoid the concat completely in order to be more efficient with memory. I am hoping for something like this:
# I am COMPLETELY making this syntax up for conceptual purposes, my apologies.
dfResultsWithoutConcat = [df1, df2, df3].apply(lambda x: someFunction(df1['A'], df1['B'], df2['C'], df3['D']), axis = 1)
```

Comment: it's difficult to understand if this is worth answering as your current problem can solved without applying a lambda and concatenating, can you explain what you're **really** trying to achieve

Comment: In my example code I start with three dataframes [df1, df2, df3]. I then need to create an intermediate dataframe called dfConsolodated that is simply the three underlying dataframes all joined together. This is fine with the toy problem, but when I am operating on >60 million records per data frame, I can bloat up the memory very quickly with the dfConsolodated table. The real goal, is to conserve system resources by avoiding the concat in the first place.

Comment: Are all of the DataFrames the same shape?

Comment: Sort of, they have the same index. They are the same height vertically, but may have different widths.

Comment: If memory is your constraint, you may be able to stick to your original workflow by concatenating the DataFrames.  However, try processing them in batches (e.g. 1m rows), and then concatenating the results.

Comment: Yes that's probably what I will end up doing. Ultimately I am populating the dataframes from SQL queries so I can throttle the data set down in the SQL layer. I'll just iterate through each mini batch until I'm done. My hope in this thread was to have learned a new way to utilize lambda.

Comment: @jtrowbridge: If your dataframe only contains numerical data then you're probably better off with numpy arrays. The only benefit in your case is being able to reference columns with column names inplace of array indices. You can always do df1.values to get back an np.array. However, you can create fast, np.vectorize'd function that can take in a sequence of np.arrays as arguments. Remember that unless you have datetimes, strings, null values, etc then you aren't really benefiting from pandas. You really just have a wrapper around numpy (obviously oversimplifying the value of pandas here!).

Comment: Excellent advice. I didn't realize what the difference was between panda df and numpy arrays. I have some string data in the table that I was using as a key. I'll hash the string based key into unique integers and run as a np.array. I'll try and report my finding back to this thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to explicitly create the desired aggregations:

```
theSum = df1.A + df1.B
theAverage = (df1.A + df1.B + df2.C + df3.D) / 4.
theProduct = df1.B * df2.C * df3.D
theResult = pd.concat([theSum, theAverage, theProduct])
theResult.columns = ['Sum', 'Average', 'Product']
```

Another possibility is to use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#query-use-cases), but this really depends on your use case and how you intend to aggregate your data.  Here is an example per the docs that might be applicable for you.

```
map(lambda frame: frame.query(expr), [df, df2])
```

Comment: This works in the example because the math in my example is simple. In reality, I am using a more sophisticated statistical model that uses some numerical integration. I don't think I can get away with explicitly creating the aggregations. Due to the complexity of the model, I think I am stuck with passing data into the function arguments.

Comment: I should mention that the query idea is worth looking into, thanks for the idea I'll give it a whirl. Back to my original question, is it even possible to use lambda across multiple, individual, data frames?

Comment: I notice you are a finance guy. I am actually creating a large dataframe that consists of a time series of daily option positions and I am pricing them through a european black-scholes model to get price and all of the typical greeks. I'm then computing daily P&L attribution across the greeks to obtain daily time series of P&L that is attributed to all the relevant sensitivities. I can't run BS by explicitly creating the aggregations as you mentioned before.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question is kind of old, but here is a way I came up with.
It is not nice, but it works.

The basic idea is to query the second dataframe inside the applied function.
By using the name of the passed series, you can identfiy the column/index and use it to retrieve the needed value from the other dataframe(s).

```
def func(x, other):
    other_value = other.loc[x.name]
    return your_actual_method(x, other_value)

result = df1.apply(lambda x: func(x, df2))
```