# pandas apply lambda multiple arguments no query different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, dataframe, apply

I noticed previous versions of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077382/pandas-applying-lambda-to-multiple-data-frames) suggested the use of queries, but I have unique data frames that do not have the same column names. I want to code this formula without for loops and only with apply function:

[image]

Here is the variables initialized. mu=μ and the other variables are as follows:

```
mu=pd.DataFrame(0, index=['A','B','C'], columns=['x','y'])  
pij=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(500,3),columns=['A','B','C'])
X=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(500,2),columns=['x','y'])
```

Next, I am able to use nested for loops to solve this

```
for j in range(len(mu)):
    for i in range(len(X)): 
        mu.ix[j,:]+=pij.ix[i,j]*X.ix[i,['x','y']]
    mu.ix[j,:]=(mu.ix[j,:])/(pij.ix[:,j].sum())

mu
          x         y
A  0.147804  0.169263
B -0.299590 -0.828494
C -0.199637  0.363423
```

My question is if it is possible to not use the nested for loops or even remove one for loop to solve this. I have made feeble attempts to no avail.

Even my initial attempts result in multiple NaN's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you pasted suggests you meant the index on mu on the left hand side of the formula to be `j`, so I'll assume that's the case.

Also since you generated random matrices for your example, my results will turn out different than yours, but I checked that your pasted code gives the same results as my code on the matrices I generated.

The numerator of the RHS of the formula can be computed with the appropriate [transpose](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) and [matrix multiplication](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html):

```
>>> num = pij.transpose().dot(X)
>>> num
           x          y
A -30.352924 -22.405490
B  14.889298 -16.768464
C -24.671337   9.092102
```

The denominator is simply [summing over columns](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
>>> denom = pij.sum()
>>> denom
A    23.460325
B    20.106702
C   -46.519167
dtype: float64
```

Then the "division" is [element-wise division by column](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.divide.html):

```
>>> num.divide(denom, axis='index')
          x         y
A -1.293798 -0.955037
B  0.740514 -0.833974
C  0.530348 -0.195449
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd normalize `pij` first then take inner product with X.  The formula looks like:

```
mu = (pij / pij.sum()).T.dot(X)
```